# Using single spring application context for web app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` and `org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet` in the same app but each is loading own application context, I need to load all beans in a single application context.

The application consists of typical layers web>app>dao etc

What I have tried is to use one single `spring-root-context.xml` by setting it in the `contextConfigLocation`.

But didn't help, this has been an issue for me for a long time an I would appreciate any help with this.

Any online references would be a great help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need here is the [`ContextLoaderListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html). This is a `ServletContextListener` which creates a root `WebApplicationContext` that is shared amongst all servlets in that webapp.

Your `DispatcherServlet` and `MessageDispatcherServlet` will still create their own contexts, but each will have the root context as their parent, so they'll both be able to use beans defined in that root context, like DAOs etc. Some beans will have to remain in the servlets own contexts, such as controllers, view resolvers, SOAP endpoints, and so on, but the shared common beans can go in the root.

For an example on how to configure this, see the [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/beans.html#context-create).

Comment: Hi skaffman, thanks to your good help its working like a dream now, thank you :)

Comment: @Ramo: Glad to help. This is where you click the tick symbol next to my answer :)

Comment: link rot strikes again. So how would it be configured?

Comment: He was referring to `Convenient ApplicationContext instantiation for web applications` section of the documentation. You can view it in another version of the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-create).